# Adding array of "Picture Box" to List Control

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listbox, picturebox

Friends,

How to add Array of PictureBox controls to the Listbox ? My requirement is to display N number of images from the directory to the PictureBoxes on Windows form.

I am able to generate N number of picture boxes dynamically, but how to add them in a listbox control with scroll bar option.

I cannot use ListView as the image size limitation is only (256,256)

Please suggest some option to achieve it.

Regards,
VHK

Comment: Use a `TableLayoutPanel` or `FlowLayoutPanel`.

Answer (score 1):

`ListBox` doesn't accept child controls. What you can do is:

- Add the `Image`s to the `ListBox.Items` directly (or wrap them in a helper class if you want to add ie. the filename of the image)
- Set the `DrawMode` to `OwnerDrawFixed`
- Handle the `DrawItem` event to paint the corresponding image